# How to get correct UTF-8 charset result with XMLWorkerHelper class in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, character-encoding, itext, xmlworker

I'm trying to convert HTML to PDF in Android with iTextPDF xmlWorker tool.
I can get PDF file. But some characters disappear after PDF created.

**My Code:**

```
private void pdfCreate (String filePath) {

        try {

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
            fileNameAndPath = filePath + File.separator + timeStamp + ".pdf";


            String d1 = "<html><head></head><body>İstanbul, Ankara, İzmir, Çanakkale</body></html>";

            OutputStream myFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileNameAndPath));
            Document document = new Document();

            document.addCreationDate();
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            document.setMargins(36, 36, 36, 36);
            document.setMarginMirroring(true);


            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, myFile);
            document.open();

            XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

            InputStream is;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(d1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            } else
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(d1.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            String FONT = "assets/fonts/arial.ttf";
            XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
            fontImp.register(FONT);

            worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), fontImp);

            document.close();
            myFile.close();



    }
```

**Result:**

"İ", "ı" are disappear. I tried stringbuilder and some another methods.

[image: PDF View]

Comment: "Every text inside a PDF can be extracted" is a persistent myth. Can you *copy* these texts correctly out of the PDF?

Comment: thx @RadLexus. I tried many technique. Replace unicode, Adding different fonts. But finally I add font-family tag for body and it work now.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution at last. Just added body **style** font-family like external font name.

**Last Codes**

```
private void pdfCreate (String filePath) {

        try {

            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
            fileNameAndPath = filePath + File.separator + timeStamp + ".pdf";

    String d1 = "<html><head></head><body style=\"font-family:arial\">İstanbul, Ankara, İzmir, Çanakkale</body></html>";


            OutputStream myFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileNameAndPath));
            Document document = new Document();

            document.addCreationDate();
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            document.setMargins(36, 36, 36, 36);
            document.setMarginMirroring(true);


            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, myFile);
            document.open();

            XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

            InputStream is;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(d1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            } else
                is = new ByteArrayInputStream(d1.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            String FONT = "assets/fonts/arial.ttf";
            XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
            fontImp.register(FONT);

            worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), fontImp);

            document.close();
            myFile.close();



    }
```

Comment: Solved my problem of hindi language not working, specially i need to put fonts in html too.